# Is it possible to prevent standard HTML comments from showing up in source code?

Tags: php, html, comments

I'm going to assume the answer is 'no' here, but since I haven't actually found that answer, I'm asking.

Quite basically, all I want to do is leave some HTML commenting in my files for 'author eyes only', simply to make editing the file later a much more pleasant experience.

`<!-- Doing it like this -->` leaves nice clean comments but they show up when viewing the page source after output.

I am using PHP, so technically I could `<?PHP /* wrap comments in PHP tags */ ?>` which would prevent them from being output at all, but if possible I'd like to avoid all of the extra arbitrary PHP tagging that would be needed for commenting throughout the file.  After all, the point of commenting is to make the document feel less cluttered and more organized.

Is there anything else I could try or are these my best options?

Comment: Best option is `<?PHP /* wrap comments in PHP tags */ ?>`, just like you already mentioned.

Comment: You could write a JS function to remove them also.  I'd stick with the PHP though.

Comment: @romo A JS function wouldn't help at all. Browsers don't run javascript on the source when you view it :/

Comment: if you can find the right names for your vars, functions, method and classess there is no need of adding many comments ... correct code ident too ... so if you can write a well structired code you will read it as you read a book ... never use html comments when theay are PHP related ... but if you still think that you need it maka a function which shows the comment when for example $_DEBUG is set - `function show_debug_commnet($msg='') { if ($_DEBUG) { echo "<!--$msg-->";}}` ... or similar ... when you need to check the generated HTML code on DEBUG

Comment: @Reflective - I use Notepad++ for my coding, and since there is syntax coloring, using actual comments is the best way to quickly find the sections I'm looking for, even if the code itself is written cleanly.  Additionally, this is why using PHP commenting was not my first choice, since the PHP tags will be colored differently than the comments they will be wrapping.

Answer (score 2):

No, anything in html will show up.

You could, have a script that parses the code, and removes the comments, before it puts it up on the server, and then you would have the original, and the uncommented source.

A tool to accomplish this:
http://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/

Comment: This is what I would suggest. Using PHP will work, but you might decide later to move from PHP to another language and, at worst, have a mess on your hands or, at best, have to run a find/replace to change all the PHP comments.

Comment: Here is something that does just this, intended to be used before deployment to testing - http://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/

Answer (score 0):

I guess these are your best options, yes, unless you run the entire HTML output through some sort of cleanup module before being sent to the client.

Anything not wrapped in server side syntax will will be output to the client if not modified on its way out (through template engines, for example). This goes for most (probably all) server side languages).

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely write a parser that uses regex to strip out HTML comments, but unless you're already dealing with a roll-your-own CMS, most likely the work involved in this far outweighs the benefits of not using PHP comments as you suggested.